# Getting php value into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
var cookieorigem = getCookie("Origem")
var cookieactionpay = getCookie("Actionpay")
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
if(cookieorigem == "actionpay" )
    {
    document.write("<img src=//apypxl.com/ok/6266.png?actionpay="+cookieactionpay+"&apid="<?php echo $orderId;?>"&price="<?php echo $orderValue;?>"&width=1&height=1 />");
}
```

But it's returning this error when  check on mozilla console:
    **SyntaxError: expected expression, got '?'**

Anybody can help me?

Comment: how/where are you executing this code? the only possible `?` in there would be the PHP opening tags, suggesting that this is in all in a `.js` file, where PHP doesn't execute.

Comment: This would only and only work if the script you just wrote is located inline in a PHP file, e.g. index.php

Answer (score 0):

You're messing up your quote marks. Try this:

```
document.write("<img src=//apypxl.com/ok/6266.png?actionpay="+cookieactionpay+"&apid=<?php echo $orderId;?>&price=<?php echo $orderValue;?>&width=1&height=1 />");
```

Your string was being terminated after `apid=` so the PHP echo wasn't happening inside the string.

Edit: the resulting script would have  looked like this with your original code:

```
document.write("<img src=//apypxl.com/ok/6266.png?actionpay="+cookieactionpay+"&apid="48"&price="3.99"&width=1&height=1 />");
```

(And, as mentioned in comments above, this does need to be in a `.php` file as well)

Comment: I'll try it. You thing because of it the pixel it's not firing?